# Toast not working from fragment of Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabbed-interface

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow but still not able to find a way through. I am trying to toast from a fragment of a Tabbed Activity but it looks like the OnClickListener is not working. Please help me out. Here is my code:

```
Button b;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View ph=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
    b=(Button)ph.findViewById(R.id.hb);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("test", "test");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "HISTORY TAB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return ph;
}
```

The fragment_history layout code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="molecule.tabfinal.History">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TAPPAL HISTORY TAB"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/hb"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="HISTORY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` and getting `Log.d("test", "test");` in logcat?

Comment: I have tried using getActivity() but it doesn't works. Yes I was checking whether the OnClickListener is working or not. I guess its not working because there is nothing in the logcat.

Comment: Ok attach debugger  in `onCreateView` method then check method is executing or not

Comment: i am getting this in the log cat:

  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference

at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:476)

at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1100)

at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:550)

at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)

Comment: post your `fragment_history` xml layout

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: have added the code you asked for. Please have a look.

Comment: @RahulKumar for now try to set the width and height of your `textview` to `wrap_content` and set the button `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin did what you said, nothing changed.